# Is there an explanation for a classifier achieving high F1 scores, but having still high CrossEntropyLoss?

Tags: overfitting, accuracy, convolution, cross-entropy, f1

I am training a CNN classifier on a balanced dataset (around 35k examples for each label) with 13 classes. The model seems to achieve high F1 scores from the first batches; The [F1 score](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.f1_score.html) for each class is ~0.99. Yet, the [CrossEntropyLoss](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss.html) remains at high levels, around 1.7. I will add below a sample output:

```
Train: [   0/3523 ( 0%)]   Average Loss: 2.565531   Average Accuracy: 0.08   Average F1 scores: [0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.16, 0.00, 0.06, 0.00, 0.00, 0.27, 0.10]
Train: [  50/3523 ( 1%)]   Average Loss: 2.516062   Average Accuracy: 0.17   Average F1 scores: [0.04, 0.02, 0.03, 0.28, 0.00, 0.00, 0.16, 0.16, 0.04, 0.20, 0.00, 0.02, 0.07]
Train: [ 100/3523 ( 2%)]   Average Loss: 2.562308   Average Accuracy: 0.13   Average F1 scores: [0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.21, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.07, 0.00, 0.20, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00]
Train: [ 150/3523 ( 4%)]   Average Loss: 2.540315   Average Accuracy: 0.15   Average F1 scores: [0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.26, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.23, 0.00, 0.06, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00]
Train: [ 200/3523 ( 5%)]   Average Loss: 2.542710   Average Accuracy: 0.15   Average F1 scores: [0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.25, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.18, 0.00, 0.21, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00]
Epoch     5: reducing learning rate of group 0 to 2.5000e-03.
Train: [ 250/3523 ( 7%)]   Average Loss: 2.295950   Average Accuracy: 0.39   Average F1 scores: [0.56, 0.00, 0.45, 0.60, 0.43, 0.25, 0.44, 0.44, 0.00, 0.36, 0.22, 0.00, 0.00]
Train: [ 300/3523 ( 8%)]   Average Loss: 2.058512   Average Accuracy: 0.63   Average F1 scores: [0.84, 0.59, 0.73, 0.86, 0.83, 0.65, 0.71, 0.64, 0.00, 0.58, 0.73, 0.00, 0.00]
Train: [ 350/3523 ( 9%)]   Average Loss: 1.947792   Average Accuracy: 0.75   Average F1 scores: [0.92, 0.91, 0.79, 0.90, 0.97, 0.76, 0.86, 0.71, 0.00, 0.72, 0.82, 0.14, 0.40]
Train: [ 400/3523 (11%)]   Average Loss: 1.801758   Average Accuracy: 0.90   Average F1 scores: [0.96, 0.94, 0.90, 0.93, 0.97, 0.91, 0.95, 0.95, 0.52, 0.89, 0.96, 0.77, 0.91]
Train: [ 450/3523 (12%)]   Average Loss: 1.758999   Average Accuracy: 0.95   Average F1 scores: [0.97, 0.98, 0.92, 0.95, 0.96, 0.93, 0.97, 0.95, 0.92, 0.91, 0.96, 0.92, 0.95]
Train: [ 500/3523 (14%)]   Average Loss: 1.747357   Average Accuracy: 0.96   Average F1 scores: [0.97, 0.97, 0.94, 0.96, 0.97, 0.91, 0.97, 0.96, 0.95, 0.96, 0.96, 0.94, 0.96]
Train: [ 550/3523 (15%)]   Average Loss: 1.728091   Average Accuracy: 0.98   Average F1 scores: [0.98, 0.99, 0.98, 0.96, 0.98, 0.97, 0.97, 0.97, 0.98, 0.97, 0.99, 0.98, 0.97]
Train: [ 600/3523 (17%)]   Average Loss: 1.717587   Average Accuracy: 0.99   Average F1 scores: [0.98, 0.99, 0.98, 0.98, 1.00, 0.98, 0.99, 0.99, 0.97, 0.98, 1.00, 0.98, 0.98]
Train: [ 650/3523 (18%)]   Average Loss: 1.711820   Average Accuracy: 0.99   Average F1 scores: [0.99, 1.00, 0.99, 0.99, 1.00, 0.99, 0.99, 1.00, 0.99, 1.00, 1.00, 0.99, 0.99]
Train: [ 700/3523 (19%)]   Average Loss: 1.715838   Average Accuracy: 0.99   Average F1 scores: [0.99, 0.99, 0.99, 0.99, 1.00, 0.98, 1.00, 0.99, 0.99, 0.97, 1.00, 0.98, 0.97]
```

Also, the performance on the test set is not that great. I achieve the same average loss of 1.7, a perfect accuracy (1.0) but mediocre F1 scores (around 0.14 for each class).

I suppose this is not overfitting, because if it was, then the loss would be way smaller.

Is there a logical explanation to this?

Comment: If the accuracy was really perfect then the F1 score should have been 1.  Are you sure you are calculating it correctly ?

Comment: @J. Delaney Yeap, I am using sklearn's built-in functions. But it is normal for the Test F1-scores to not be perfect, since the losses are high, right?

Comment: Yes but in that case you do not expect to get perfect accuracy on the test set. Looking at the precision and recall as well might help you understand what is going on